# A function to print copies of a character

Tags: c++, string

How to write a function which gets a character and the number of copies as function arguments? A sample code is below.

```
#include <string>

std::string printSplitter (int N, char C)
{
    // return string of N characters
}

int main()
{
    printSplitter (10, "-"); // prints: ----------
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string): `return std::string(N, C);`, then print the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"How to write a function which gets a character and the number of copies as function arguments?"*

As mentioned, you can implement your `printSplitter()` function simply as

```
std::string printSplitter (int N, char C) {
    return std::string(N,C);
}
```

See the reference documentation of [`std::string constructor`'s (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

---

So you probably want to have something simple like this (no need for implementing your *own* `printSplitter()`, at least I see no benefit of doing so):

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::string(10, '-') << std::endl; // prints: ----------
    return 0;
}
```

Or even simpler

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "----------" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```